# Case statement in NHibernate / EF Linq

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate, entity-framework-4

What will be the equivalent of following SQL statement in Linq? I'm specifically looking on how to replace CASE statements in Linq expression.

```
SELECT a.app_id   AS Id, 
   a.app_nm   AS [Name], 
   COUNT(CASE 
           WHEN l.level_nm = 'ERROR' THEN l.log_id 
           ELSE NULL 
         END) AS Error, 
   COUNT(CASE 
           WHEN l.level_nm = 'FATAL' THEN l.log_id 
           ELSE NULL 
         END) AS Fatal 
FROM   info_log l 
     INNER JOIN application_info a 
     ON a.app_id = l.app_id 
WHERE  l.level_nm IN ( 'ERROR', 'FATAL' ) 
GROUP  BY a.app_id, 
          a.app_nm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out

```
var query = from l in context.info_log
            from a in context.application_info
            where l.app_id == a.app_id
            where l.level_nm == "ERROR" || l.level_nm == "FATAL"
            group l by new { a.app_id, a.app_nm } into lg
            select new
            {
              Id = lg.Key.app_id,
              Name = lg.Key.app_nm,
              Error = lg.Where(x => x.level_nm == "ERROR").Count(),
              Fatal = lg.Where(x => x.level_nm == "FATAL").Count(),
            };
```

Comment: Thanks. Your sample with join statements included works fine with EF but doesn't work with NHibernate. I get same count for Error and Fatal in NHibernate. Any idea?

Comment: @Raj - It looks like NHibernate is ignoring the Where clause. I can't test on it right now either